# Is there an error-correcting code where almost every word could be used as a codeword?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, cryptography, coding-theory

An error-correcting code for strings of length $n$ from a $K$ letter alphabet is a partition $\Pi$ of $K^n$ together with a choice function $\pi$ on $\Pi$.  Let $A_i$ for $i<M$ enumerate $\Pi$, and imagine that there are $M$ different possible messages you want to be able to transmit across a noisy channel (one that can change symbols in the string).  You use the error-correcting code by encoding message $i$ as $\pi(A_i)$ for transmission and decoding a received message as the index of the element of $\Pi$ it belongs to.  Clearly a good code will have the properties that $\Pi$ is large, and for any $A\in \Pi$, $\pi(A)$ differs at many locations from any string not in $A$.  But what can we show about how rare it can be for a randomly picked string to differ at few locations from a string in a different partition element?

This question comes from one I asked on Crypto Stack Exchange: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19340/is-deniable-error-correction-possible

Comment: The more codewords you have, the fewer errors you can correct: every time you detect an error you actually deem the word in question incorrect. In other words, if every word is a codeword, you cannot detect anything, because with any change it is still a proper codeword.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the question.  Please read the question itself, not just the title.

Comment: Indeed. Perhaps fixing this issue, and making your post easier to parse would attract more attention, not only such lazy bums as me, who require such outrageous things as readable questions...

Comment: As for the Alice and Bob, you say that Bob _can recover Alice's original 1000 bit string_, in other words, for Bob the 2000 bit string has only 1000 bits of entropy. If sent over perfect channel, there is no way Bob would mistake it for a random sequence. If you could ensure that the channel would mess with the data to re-add the missing entropy, then for sure Bob could be fooled (i.e. enough entropy to fool Bob, but not too much, so that it is possible to recover the message). However, that would be a rather strong assumption.

Comment: Your first comment is spot on.  For the question title issue, do you have an suggestion?

Comment: I don't really understand the second comment.  Maybe if Alice sent on the order of $2^{1000}$ messages and Bob had the resources to log them all the entropy would come into play, but I was supposing she only sent one message and that Bob had bounded resources.  If Bob has bounded resources, one thing he can still do is check whether there is a string that decodes to something different that is a short Hamming distance from the transmitted string.  If a non-negligible proportion of strings have this property, information will be leaking about whether the transmitted string was random.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of an answer/example you are looking for. You make it sound like the function $\pi$ should be computable for any input from $K^n$ (that is feasible for some classes of codes, but not for most). If you just want probabilities that a random string is within a certain Hamming distance from a codeword **of a known code**, then that is easy to calculate (if within certain error correction capability of the code) and to upper bound otherwise. If the code is unknown, then a single message won't leak anything, because you can one-time-pad the entire codebook.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The question does not discuss computability or computational complexity.  Maybe a code could be such that on certain inputs the decoding program just throws up its hands and says it has no idea what the original data was, but you don't really lose generality with the way I defined error-correcting codes because you could replace the throwing up of hands with the issuance of some arbitrarily chosen fixed answer, like all zeroes, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The probability that a random string is within a certain Hamming distance from a codeword does not interest me.  I am interested in the probability that a random string is within a certain Hamming distance of a string that decodes to something else.  In fact, for the problem I am really interested, we don't even need to assume that the same message is always encoded in the same way.  It is really $\Pi$ that matters, not $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure that I understood the question. Therefore I post this toy example calculation as an answer. Mostly to get the ball rolling.

Assume that $K=2$, $n=23$ and we use the perfect 3-error correcting binary Golay code $G$. Let the partition $\Pi$ consist of the bounded distance decision regions of $G$. In other words, if $\vec{x}_i$ is the $i$th word of $G$, $i=1,2,\ldots,4096$, then
$$
A_i=\{\vec{y}\in\{0,1\}^{23}\mid d(\vec{y},\vec{x}_i)\le3\}.
$$
Because the Golay code is perfect, these regions form a seamless partition of the entire space. We see that $A_i$ contains the vector $\vec{x}_i$, the $23$ vectors at distance $1$ from it, the ${23\choose2}=253$ vectors at distance $2$ from it, and finally ${23\choose3}=1771$ vectors at Hamming distance three from $\vec{x}_i$. Altogether $1+23+253+1771=2048=2^{11}$ vectors (in accordance to perfectness the $2^{12}$ such partition regions contain all the $2^{23}$ possible messages.

If I understood the question correctly, we are interested in the probability of a randomly chosen vector from the set $A_i$ being close to a vector from another partition $A_j,j\neq i$. Let us consider the case, where we specify *close* to mean *at Hamming distance one*. Here's what happens in our case. If $\vec{y}\in A_i$ is at Hamming distance three from $\vec{x}_i$, then it is at Hamming distance one from $23-3=20$ vectors $\vec{z}$ with the property $d(\vec{z},\vec{x}_i)=4$. This is easy to understand: we got to $\vec{y}$ from $\vec{x}_i$ by toggling three out of 23 bits, so by toggling any of the 20 remaining bits we keep moving away from $\vec{x}_i$.
So none of those 20 vectors $\vec{z}$ belong to $A_i$, so they belong to some other partition.

What this means is that if we select a random vector from the set $A_i$, then it will be within Hamming distance one from a vector of some other partition $A_j, j\neq i$ with probability $1771/2048\approx 0.86475$.

I don't know if this probability is good news or bad news for you. I want to make two more remarks.

- I used a perfect code here to make the description of the partition as well as the calculation easy. I need to warn you that in general things become very messy, because there are darn few perfect codes (and all but the Golay code and repetition codes of length $n$ and rate $1/n$ can only correct a single error). This means that the partitions won't have this "spherical" shape. There will be regions that are somewhat distant from all the centers of the regions. I guess this would tend to increase the above probability, but my intuition is somewhat underdeveloped to make such a claim with any kind of confidence.
- Anyway, what we witnessed above is an example of the following maxim:

> In a high dimensional space the bulk of the volume of an approximately spherical region is close to its boundary.
>   
>   If we spend too much time staring at 2-dimensional pictures, such as tiling the plane with squares, triangles or hexagons, we may develop the intuitive feeling that most of the area is relatively far away from the boundaries of those regions. This is a low-dimensional fallacy.

Comment: Thanks for this thoughtful response.  It would be bad news for me if these boundary regions always had to be large; I would like them to be very small.  One way to get small boundaries is to encode each bit by repeating it some large number $R$ times.  The probability that changing any given bit will change the partition element will then be about $\sqrt{2/(\pi R)}$ by Stirling's approximation of the binomial formula.  But this repetition coding lacks the Shannon property that for some fixed transmission rate you can do arbitrarily well.

Comment: I suspect, as I sense you do, that getting the Shannon property is in some sense incompatible with having a coding where the boundary regions are small.  But I don't know what the exact theorem would be or how to prove it.  Also, the Shannon property is so great that one might suspect there is some much stronger impossibility result than just that you can't have it.  For instance, a result that says you can't do better than repetition coding.

Comment: Minor correction: I should have said $2\sqrt{2/(\pi R)}$.

Comment: @gmr You do get something like that if your code is a pure repetition code. But if you repeat more than one bit, it quickly becomes worse. If you repeat a single bit $7$ times, then the probability of being at the boundary is $p={7\choose 3}/2^6\approx 0.547$. But if your code is longer, and you repeat, say, $n$ bits seven times each, then a random vector in the partition $A_i$ will be at the boundary if at least one of the groups of seven bits is. This happens at probability $1-(1-p)^n$ which quickly $\to1$ as $n$ increases.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was getting at.  But that isn't a proof that there's not some clever way to do much better than repetition coding. @JyrkiLahtonen